# Can I call an API to set/unset a user as "off work" in skype for business?

Tags: api, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

We have a Skype for Business 2015 deployment and I would like to automate presence such that employees that are clocked out automatically become "off work" in skype, and are changed from "off work" to something like "away" when they clock in.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a [trusted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn466044.aspx) [UCMA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn454984.aspx) application.  You can then create [UserEndpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn466053.aspx)'s and [publish](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn466002.aspx) whatever presence you like at whatever time your like for whatever lync users you like.